# Ubuntu high processor utilization with no identifiable processes consuming processor

Tags: ubuntu, malware, top, htop

Ubuntu host with 100% utilization in top or htop.

When I inspect the running processes, I don't see a process consuming a significant amount of CPU resources.

I've tried using commands like top, htop, and ps to list the running processes, but none of them indicate any process responsible for the high CPU usage. I  checked for background tasks or services, but haven't found anything unusual.

Could anyone suggest possible reasons for this behavior and how I might identify the cause of the high CPU usage in this scenario? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

[top sort by cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm1Qd.jpg)

[htop sort by cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYqEK.jpg)

[iotop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgYY8.jpg)

Yesterday, I used 'unhide' to uncover hidden processes, but I couldn't terminate them using 'kill -9'. Additionally, I couldn't identify the origins of these processes. Are there any other tools I can use? I tried using 'clamscan' to scan the root directory, but it quickly led to system restart without completion.

```
# unhide proc
Unhide 20130526
Copyright © 2013 Yago Jesus & Patrick Gouin
License GPLv3+ : GNU GPL version 3 or later
http://www.unhide-forensics.info

NOTE : This version of unhide is for systems using Linux >= 2.6

Used options:
[*]Searching for Hidden processes through /proc stat scanning

Found HIDDEN PID: 1936
        Cmdline: "/c7c564dc"
        Executable: "/c7c564dc (deleted)"
        Command: "c7c564dc"
        $USER=root
        $PWD=/

Found HIDDEN PID: 1938
        Cmdline: "/c7c564dc"
        Executable: "/c7c564dc (deleted)"
        Command: "c7c564dc"
        $USER=root
        $PWD=/
```

```
# ll /proc/1936/map_files/
total 0
dr-x------ 2 root root  0 Mar 26 10:08 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root  0 Mar 25 21:15 ../
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 400000-c2c000 -> '/c7c564dc (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fb800000-7f31fba00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fba00000-7f31fbc00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fbc00000-7f31fbe00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fbe00000-7f31fc000000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fc000000-7f31fc200000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fc200000-7f31fc400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fc400000-7f31fc600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fc600000-7f31fc800000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fc800000-7f31fca00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fca00000-7f31fcc00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fcc00000-7f31fce00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fce00000-7f31fd000000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fd000000-7f31fd200000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fd200000-7f31fd400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fd400000-7f31fd600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fd600000-7f31fd800000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fd800000-7f31fda00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fda00000-7f31fdc00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fdc00000-7f31fde00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fde00000-7f31fe000000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fe000000-7f31fe200000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fe200000-7f31fe400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fe400000-7f31fe600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fe600000-7f31fe800000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fe800000-7f31fea00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fea00000-7f31fec00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fec00000-7f31fee00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31fee00000-7f31ff000000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31ff000000-7f31ff200000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31ff200000-7f31ff400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31ff400000-7f31ff600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31ff600000-7f31ff800000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31ff800000-7f31ffa00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31ffa00000-7f31ffc00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31ffc00000-7f31ffe00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f31ffe00000-7f3200000000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3224200000-7f3224400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3224400000-7f3224600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3224600000-7f3224800000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3224800000-7f3224a00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3224a00000-7f3224c00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3224c00000-7f3224e00000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3224e00000-7f3225000000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3225000000-7f3225200000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3225200000-7f3225400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3225400000-7f3225600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3244200000-7f3244400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3244400000-7f3244600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3274200000-7f3274400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3274400000-7f3274600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3294200000-7f3294400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3294400000-7f3294600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f32ac200000-7f32ac400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f32ac400000-7f32ac600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f32c4200000-7f32c4400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f32c4400000-7f32c4600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3304200000-7f3304400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3304400000-7f3304600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3314200000-7f3314400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3314400000-7f3314600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f331c200000-7f331c400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f331c400000-7f331c600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3324200000-7f3324400000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3324400000-7f3324600000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3326000000-7f3336000000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lrw------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f3336000000-7f33b8000000 -> '/anon_hugepage (deleted)'
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc31c000-7f33cc320000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc320000-7f33cc330000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc330000-7f33cc334000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc334000-7f33cc335000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc335000-7f33cc336000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc338000-7f33cc339000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc339000-7f33cc33d000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc33d000-7f33cc33e000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc33e000-7f33cc33f000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc33f000-7f33cc340000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc340000-7f33cc343000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc343000-7f33cc34a000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc34a000-7f33cc34c000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc34c000-7f33cc34d000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cc34d000-7f33cc34e000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceb7b000-7f33ceb9d000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceb9d000-7f33ced15000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ced15000-7f33ced63000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ced63000-7f33ced67000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ced67000-7f33ced69000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ced6d000-7f33ced7a000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ced7a000-7f33cee21000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cee21000-7f33ceeba000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceeba000-7f33ceebb000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceebb000-7f33ceebc000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceebc000-7f33ceebd000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceebd000-7f33ceebf000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceebf000-7f33ceec0000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceec0000-7f33ceec1000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceec1000-7f33ceec2000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceec2000-7f33ceec4000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceec4000-7f33ceec8000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceec8000-7f33ceeca000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceeca000-7f33ceecb000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceecb000-7f33ceecc000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.31.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceecc000-7f33ceed2000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceed2000-7f33ceee3000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceee3000-7f33ceee9000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceee9000-7f33ceeea000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceeea000-7f33ceeeb000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceef9000-7f33ceefa000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33ceefa000-7f33cef1d000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cef1d000-7f33cef25000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cef26000-7f33cef27000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 7f33cef27000-7f33cef28000 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so*
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 e2b000-e5f000 -> '/c7c564dc (deleted)'
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:08 e5f000-e6d000 -> '/c7c564dc (deleted)'
```

```
# ll /proc/1936/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 root root  0 Mar 26 10:08 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root  0 Mar 25 21:15 ../
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 10 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 11 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 12 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 13 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 14 -> 'socket:[531426]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 16 -> 'socket:[530634]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 17 -> 'socket:[531425]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 2 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 3 -> 'pipe:[32178]'
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 4 -> /dev/urandom
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 5 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 6 -> 'pipe:[170]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 7 -> 'pipe:[170]'
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 8 -> 'pipe:[43169]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 26 10:10 9 -> 'pipe:[43169]'
```

Comment: how many cores does the server have? you aren't worried about the load level? what does `dmesg` is telling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High load without explanation](https://serverfault.com/questions/139234/high-load-without-explanation)

Comment: High CPU load from a hidden process? You got malware.

Comment: @djdomi 64 cores, all is 100% usage； The dmesg output doesn't seem to show any abnormalities. Maybe
[Mon Mar 25 01:36:01 2024] iptable_reject: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[Mon Mar 25 01:36:01 2024] iptable_reject: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

Comment: @AlexD How can I proceed to locate and remove the virus? When I execute the clamscan command, it directly leads to a system reboot without completing.

Comment: That `iptable_reject` module is most likely the malware. There is no such module in a normal system.

Comment: hm, even if the server has been hijacked, try installing unhide, moreover `modprobe -r name` removes name but the load level is not reffering that 64 cores are at 100%, however I agree to consider that the server may hijacked. also consider that all readable passwords are also off your control. also verify with lsmod  if the module is loaded like Alex said

Comment: @wuyeguo You reimage the system.

Comment: Is this a LXC container? VM? Bare metal installation?